# Render the Material UI Menu as <nav> and its children as <a>?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've a Material UI `Menu`, redered as `<div>` > `<ul>` `<li>` by default. I wanto to turn it into a `<div>` `<nav>` `<a>`.

I'm able to change `MenuItem` and turn into a `<a>`. But I can't find a way to turn the `<ul>` into a `<nav>`, there is no `component` prop. Material UI is so customizable that I'm sure I'm missing something and it's my mistake.

```
<Menu open={true}>
  <MenuItem component='a'>Profile</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem component='a'>Settings</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem component='a'>Logout</MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

I can also use the [MenuList API](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/menu-list/#main-content) as child of `Menu`, but it only render another level below the `<ul>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MenuList` inherits the [props](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/menu-list/#props) from the `List` component which you can use to change the `ul` to a `nav`

```js
<Menu
  open={true}
  MenuListProps={{
    "aria-labelledby": "basic-button",
    component: "nav"
  }}
>
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but I still get the error: Type '{ component: string; 'aria-labelledby': string; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<MenuListProps>. Ideas?

Comment: No unfortunately not, it seems like the `ul` is hard coded in the type `Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'component' does not exist in type 'Partial<MenuListProps<"ul", {}>>'`